# Detectar si una variable incrementa o disminuye

Tags: javascript

Me interesa saber cómo puedo detectar si una variable aumenta o disminuye su cantidad usando javascript

```js
var x = 0;

if (x > ) {
document.write("Aumenta");
} else if (x < ) {
document.write("Disminuye");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar `setInterval` para verificar que dicha variable aumente o disminuye en tiempo real

De esta forma

```js
  var x = 100;
  var y = x; // con esto guardamos el anterior valor de 'x'
  setInterval(function() {
    if (x > y) {
      console.log("Aumenta", x);
    } else {
      console.log("Disminuye", x);
    }
  }, 1000);
  // esto de abajo solo es para hacer una demostración
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    x++; // con esto aumentamos el valor de 'x'
    // puedes cambiar los dos signos '++' por '--' para disminuir
    // esto solo para que la consola no se sature
    if (x >= 110 || x <= 80) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 1000);
```

---

**Editado**

Aquí una versión un poco mas corta, usando una condición ternaria

```js
  var text;
  var x = 100;
  var y = x; // con esto guardamos el anterior valor de 'x'
  setInterval(function() {
    text = (x > y) ? "Aumenta" : "Disminuye";
    console.log(text, x);
  }, 1000);
  // esto de abajo solo es para hacer una demostración
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    x++; // con esto aumentamos el valor de 'x'
    // puedes cambiar los dos signos '++' por '--' para disminuir
    // esto solo para que la consola no se sature
    if (x >= 110 || x <= 80) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 1000);
```

---

**Bonus**

Ahora que si lo que quieres es chequear que un objeto cambie en tiempo real, puedes usar `object.watch`

De esta forma

```
var i = {x:5};
i.watch("x", function (id, oldval, newval) {
    newval > oldval ? console.log('Disminuye') : console.log('Aumenta');
    return newval;
});
```

- Documentación de [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/watch)